# How do i create a responsive table for small screen sizes less than 600

Tags: css, mobile, html-table, media-queries, responsive

I need help scaling down the overall size of the table to fit all screen sizes, most sizes I've covered but can't scale down for mobile screen sizes 600 or less. I mostly use flex box in the media query but can't get the size down less that 600. i'm missing something but can't put my finger on it.
See my code and please advise what i'm missing. any help i'm grateful for. 
I'll kick myself i'm sure..

```css
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.table td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: black;
}

.table th {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
    border-color: black;
}

.table .index-table {
    border-color: inherit;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) and (max-width: 1025px)and (max-width: 300px) {
    .table {
        overflow-x: auto;
    }
    .index-table {
        width: auto !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="index-table" colspan="15">Seattle</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="15">Hinged Shutter Specification</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="3" rowspan="3">Louver Size</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="8">Width</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="4" rowspan="2">Height</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="2">Min</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="6">Max</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2">Single Hung</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2">Bi-Fold</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2">Multi-Fold</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2">Min.</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2">Max*</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="3" rowspan="2">47mm</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="10">152mm</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="2">600mm</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="10">600mm</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="10">N/A</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="10">250mm</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="10">300mm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="3" rowspan="2">63mm</td>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="2" rowspan="8">750mm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="3" rowspan="2">76mm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="3" rowspan="2">89mm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="index-table" colspan="3" rowspan="2">114mm</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is making your website/page mobile friendly. To do that you have to setup the viewport, You can do so by adding:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

in the `head` tag in your `html` file and your good to go. Read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).

Comment: yea i have that already, the table does shrink but stops and all other content to shrinks and the table remains the same size